# Check Mark in iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I am building a pdf. I would like to have some text and next to the text a check mark. Does anyone have an idea as to how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a PNG of a check mark, load the image and draw it next to your text.  I've done something similar many times but not specifically with iTextSharp.  Here is an iText [example](http://1t3xt.info/examples/browse/?page=example&id=77) to get you started though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for checkmarks as bullets :

```
List myList = new ZapfDingbatsList(52);
```

`ZapfDingbatsList(52)` - checkmark in bold.
`ZapfDingbatsList(51)` - checkmark in normal.